# Enabling a grayed out dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like the "Region" form to be grayed out unless the user selected "Player" from the first "Type" form. Here's what I have

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="submitform.php">
Search for:<br>
<input type="text" value="" name="username">
<select name="Type">
  <option value="">Select Type:</option>
  <option value="Ch">Champion</option>
  <option value="Pl">Player</option>
  <option value="It">Item</option></select>

<select name="Region">
  <option value="">Select Region:</option>
  <option value="br">BR</option>
  <option value="eune">EUNE</option>
  <option value="euw">EUW</option>
  <option value="lan">LAN</option>
  <option value="les">LES</option>
  <option value="na">NA</option>
  <option value="oce">OCE</option>
  <option value="ru">RU</option>
  <option value="tr">TR</option>
  <option value="kr">KR</option></select>
```

How can you go about doing this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="submitform.php">
Search for:<br>
<input type="text" value="" name="username">
<select name="Type" id="type">
  <option value="">Select Type:</option>
  <option value="Ch">Champion</option>
  <option value="Pl">Player</option>
  <option value="It">Item</option></select>

<select name="Region" id="region" disabled>
  <option value="">Select Region:</option>
  <option value="br">BR</option>
  <option value="eune">EUNE</option>
  <option value="euw">EUW</option>
  <option value="lan">LAN</option>
  <option value="les">LES</option>
  <option value="na">NA</option>
  <option value="oce">OCE</option>
  <option value="ru">RU</option>
  <option value="tr">TR</option>
  <option value="kr">KR</option></select>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("type").onchange = function() {
    var type = document.getElementById("type");
    var typeSelected = type.options[type.selectedIndex].text;
    if(typeSelected == "Player") {
        document.getElementById("region").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("region").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qa9ysycd/)

Comment: much appreciado, sir!

Comment: @darude24 No problem :) If it works, you can set it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick on the left hand side

Comment: i just tried it out.. the second dropdown "Region" is grayed out but it doesn't get "ungrayed" when I pick "Player" from the other dropdown. Should I have <script type=javascript> or similar around your second block?

Comment: i copied everything exactly and still no go. does it matter where i put the javascript (top of code, before the forms, after)?

Comment: @darude24 You must put the javascript code after the form, enclosed between `<script>` and `</script>`

Comment: legend! moving the javascript worked! *ticked*

Answer (score 0):

1. Add id's to your elements. (This will make coding easier.)
2. Set the Region select element to be disabled initially.
3. Add a click handler for Type to reset the disabled attribute of the Region item based on the selected Type value.